# Facebook share parameter for user note from flash

Tags: actionscript-3

Currently I'm using below link with parameters to share on facebook. This link works well.

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=testURL&p[images][0]=testImagePath&p[title]=testTilte&p[summary]=userMessage`

I also need to add the user note dynamically. Can it be possible through parameters?